# How to rotate itemLabels vertically above bars in a barChart in JasperReport

Tags: java, jasper-reports, jfreechart

I'm using Jaspersoft Studio 6.8.0 and JFreechart 1.5.0. 
I'd like to rotate vertically the item labels that appears above the bar in a Jasper Report barChart

[image]

I found some answers about this problem but they were about the previous version of JFreechart, they were using:

```
categoryPlot.getRenderer().setBasePositiveItemLabelPosition(new ItemLabelPosition(ItemLabelAnchor.OUTSIDE12, TextAnchor.BOTTOM_CENTER));
```

But this one seems deprecated (it gives me error). I tried to use this, following the documentation

```
package com.efarmgroup.sina.sios4.jasper;

import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.chart.labels.*;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.CategoryPlot;
import org.jfree.chart.renderer.category.*;
import org.jfree.chart.ui.TextAnchor;

import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRChart;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRChartCustomizer;


public class customLabelRotation implements JRChartCustomizer{

    @Override
    public void customize(JFreeChart chart, JRChart jasperChart){

        CategoryPlot categoryPlot = (CategoryPlot) chart.getPlot();
        CategoryItemRenderer renderer = categoryPlot.getRenderer();
        ItemLabelPosition itemLabelPosition = new ItemLabelPosition(ItemLabelAnchor.OUTSIDE12, TextAnchor.CENTER_LEFT, TextAnchor.CENTER_LEFT, -Math.PI / 2);
        renderer.setDefaultPositiveItemLabelPosition(itemLabelPosition);
    }
}
```

But it seems that

```
setDefaultPositiveItemLabelPosition
```

gives me error while I try to generate the report.

Any clue on how to re-write the function or how to use that kind of parameter of the label in JFreechart?

EDIT: This is the error
[image]

Comment: Among the [demos](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/samples.html), `BarChartDemo5` or `BarChartDemo7` may be helpful.

Comment: I can't really find in the demos what I'm looking for...they just stop with JFreechart 1.0.19...the API Documentation reach the 1.5.0, I followed the "Class ItemLabelPosition" found in the Doc but It doesn't work

Comment: AFAIK, both are in the 1.5 [demo](https://jfree.github.io/jfreechart-demo-programs/); you may have to tinker with the `ItemLabelPosition` settings.

Comment: @trashgod I already tried to work with the setting, the problem is that it doesnt recognize the method (I already checked, I'm using JFreechart 1.5.0, so that method should be implemented)...I edited my question to add the error

Comment: `setDefaultPositiveItemLabelPosition()` was `setBaseItemLabelGenerator()` in previous versions; yioyu may need to check your class path.

Comment: The class path is correct. The .class of the function is correctly imported, and the JFreechart 1.5.0 jar too. But I don't know why it doesn't find the ItemLabelPosition method